# slideToggle function does not work for button submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, animi quia odio eligendi! Ducimus ad fugit, sed, accusantium laboriosam vero, mollitia natus repudiandae possimus delectus laborum quidem beatae quibusdam tenetur!</p>

<input type="button" class="btnRegular" value="regular">
<input type="submit" class="btnSubmit">
```

I have the following code with some `p` text, and two `buttons`. One is a `regular button` and the other is a `"submit"` button. When I add the following jquery, only the `btnRegular` works. The `submit` button does not. Why is this? Is my jq wrong?

```
$(function () {
    //for regular putton
    $("#btnRegular").click(function () {
        $("p").slideToggle();
    });


    //for submit button
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        $("p").slideToggle();
    });





});
```

I dont think my code is wrong since it works with the regular button, but why not for the special submit button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using class on button thats why its not working

//here you are using `btnRegular` as a class

```
<input type="button" class="btnRegular" value="regular">
```

//i have changed  `btnRegular` as a id

```
<input type="button" id="btnRegular" value="regular">
```

```js
$(function () {
    //for regular putton
    $("#btnRegular").click(function() {
        $("p").slideToggle();
    });


    //for submit button
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
        $("p").slideToggle();
    });

});
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, animi quia odio eligendi! Ducimus ad fugit, sed, accusantium laboriosam vero, mollitia natus repudiandae possimus delectus laborum quidem beatae quibusdam tenetur!</p>

<input type="button" id="btnRegular" value="regular">
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: nop you can change on thing only wait , i'll explain

Comment: if my answer is use full to you , please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Because you were using class and in js you were trying to use # id selector.

```js
$(function () {
//for regular putton
$("#btnRegular").click(function () {
    $("p").slideToggle();
});


//for submit button
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
    $("p").slideToggle();
});





});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, animi quia odio eligendi! Ducimus ad fugit, sed, accusantium laboriosam vero, mollitia natus repudiandae possimus delectus laborum quidem beatae quibusdam tenetur!</p>

<input type="button" id="btnRegular" value="regular">
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit">
```